# Replacing include layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

I generated new Android project in Android Studio where i choosed the new template for blank activity with Fragment, i found out its structured a bit different then old ones. It uses  tag and CoordinatorLayout. So how should i be switching layouts inside this include tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: just put your layout code and remove include if you dont want include

Comment: what does your @layout/content_main  has?

Comment: A simple layouts like login and register form, i know i could put layout but i like the way it is. So its seperated in different files

Answer (score 3):

Replace `include` with a container, e.g. `FrameLayout`. At runtime inflate the layout you want to add, and call `addView` on the container. To replace what you already have, you call `removeView` and then `addView` with the new content

Comment: What if i would like to have a different toolbar for each fragment? The content will change but the toolbar will remains same right?

Comment: @user3289108, it will indeed stay the same

Comment: But if i would like to have different toolbar, then what should i do? I just raised a question on this. Can you look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760818/different-toolbar-for-each-fragment-in-new-coordinator-layout