# Different toolbar for each fragment or change Scroll Behaviour in new Coordinator Layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I implemented the Navigation Drawer by using the template provided by `Google` in New Android Studio 1.4. Here it automatically created everything including the layout and class.

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frame_container">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Hell World"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You could see `fragment_container` above. I simply replace this with different fragment based on item click in the Navigation drawer.
There's no issue in this too.

```
 UpdatesFragment fragment = new UpdatesFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now, I would to have a different toolbar for each fragment. How could i get the different toolbar for each fragment in this new `CoordinatorLayout`?

Or, I mean I would like to have a different Scroll Behavior for each fragment. How can i achieve this

Comment: the toolbar can stay the same. You could get a reference to it per fragment with `getActivity().getSupportActionBar()`, if you are using the toolbar as replacement for the ActionBar

Comment: Yes, but how could i change the scroll behaviour?